# table excel with multiple y results per x coordinate -> show only maximum with vba

Tags: excel, vba

I want a VBA-code that shows only the maximum y value for every value of x

My original table is shown column A and B. 
My desired result is given in column C and D.

[corrected picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNFvC.png)
I want VBA to do it because the real problem is that I have large tables with data and I have to do it several times
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1g7D.png)

Comment: Shouldn't the `1` max be `5`, not `2`?

Comment: Look up Maxifs function

Comment: Show us what you've tried.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not have MAXIFS, which is only available with Office 365 Excel, use AGGREGATE:

```
=AGGREGATE(14,6,$B$2:$B$7/($A$2:$A$7=C2),1)
```

If you are using 2007 or older then you will need to use the following array formula:

```
=MAX(IF($A$2:$A$7=C2,$B$2:$B$7))
```

Entered with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

---

But, a pivot table will probably be what you truly want.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MAXIF()`:

```
=MAXIFS($B$2:$B$7,$A$2:$A$7,C2)
```

Where

[image]

Comment: With MAXIFS, one can use full column references just like SUMIFS.

Comment: I want VBA to do it because the real problem is that I have large tables with data and I have to do it several times. And I don't want to type every unique x value in a column first.

Comment: @Hansexcelvba if you want vba then you will need to try it first on your own.  Stack Overflow is not a code for me site.  We provided formula answers as they are simple and singular.

Comment: @Hansexcelvba - Turn on the macro recorder, then copy your X's into a new column. Run Data-->Remove Duplicates. Enter the formula and you should have your VBA.  Tweak from there.